# How to load the custom field values of the post via ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am not a php programer and don't know anything about data fetching, but i am trying to make a template that loads the custom field values of the post via ajax in wordpress the reason i would like to load the values using ajax is because those fields contain lot of texts and image links so if they preloaded it will take lots of time to load whole page.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that not everybody will see these custom fields, because JavaScript is disabled for some users?

Comment: @andre_roesti Javascript being disabled is a diminishing issue. The vast majority of Internet users have javascript enabled, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript.

Answer (score 2):

**I wrote a plugin for you!** First download and install *ajax-custom* from the URL below. When the plugin is activated, insert the following template tag in your theme everywhere you need these AJAX-loaded custom-fields. Don't forget to replace `NAME OF THE FIELD` with the actual name of the custom field you want to load via AJAX.

```
<?php
if( function_exists( 'ac_placeholder' ) )
    ac_placeholder( 'NAME OF THE FIELD' );
?>
```

---

### [→Download *ajax-custom*](http://www.roesti.me/uploads/ajax-custom.zip)

---

I hope it helps you and maybe also someone else. I would appreciate a thumbs up. :)

Comment: Hi andre thanks again for the help. some more questions? I am actually building a property listing website and would like to load the custom field contents (features of the properties) inside jquary tabs with ajax request by selecting or clicking each tab. i guess that way it will prevent the page load time without loading all those custom field at the same time when viewing the post description.

Comment: @andre roesti i tried your plugin but there seems to be some problems with as it breaks the wordpress admin js functions so could you please check whats wrong